# how to insert string in continuous pattern in Linux

Tags: linux, sed

I want to insert string between symbol but the symbol is continuous.
Like ';;;;;;;;;;;'

I can use `echo ';;;;;;;;;;' | sed 's/\;\;/\;na\;/g'`, but the output will be `;na;;na;;na;;na;;na;`.

What I want is `;na;na;na;na;na;na;na;na;na;na;`.

[Update more specific question]

Like '`xx;;string;;;string;;string;;;;`'
How can I turn it into `xx;na;string;na;na;string;na;string;na;na;na;`

I want **all empty space** between "**;;**" to have na in it. Is there any command it will work? 
Is there any command it will work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another `awk` approach.

```
awk '{i=0; while(i++<2)gsub(/;;/,";na;")}1'
```

Or using `sed`:

```
sed ':l;s/;;/;na;/;tl'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: For the first one, it will have addtion ";" at the end.
2nd one is wonderful.

Comment: @sowrdking that's because you revised your question and it only works at that time. now I removed old command and keep only the command which resolves your current stated question.

Comment: Both solution works, and I can use the first one in FreeBSD, too.

Answer (score 3):

Try this `sed` method also

```
sed 's/;/&na/g;s/$/;/' <<< ';;;;;;;;;;'
```

**Output:**

```
;na;na;na;na;na;na;na;na;na;na;
```

**Explanation:**

`s/;/&na/g`  -   append `na` in each `;`
`s/$/;/` -  add `;` in end of the line , so that it will fulfill the requirment

Comment: Yeah, Thanks :)-

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Kalanidhi Question is revised now, and your command adding an extra `na;` at the end + will fail for the repeated `;`s like in `xx;;xx;;;;x`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do ...

```
$ echo ';;;;;;;;;;' | sed 's/\;/\;na/g'
;na;na;na;na;na;na;na;na;na;na
```

If you need the trailing ; do ...

```
$ echo `echo ';;;;;;;;;;' | sed 's/\;/\;na/g'`\;
;na;na;na;na;na;na;na;na;na;na;
```

Answer (score 0):

using **awk**

```
$ echo "xx;;string;;;string;;string;;;;" | awk -v FS="" '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i==";" && $(i-1)==";") printf "na"$i; else printf $i;  printf RS}'
xx;na;string;na;na;string;na;string;na;na;na;
```